# How to select value to be the value in the property step in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune, gremlin-server, gremlinjs

I'm trying to select a value from an injected array and set it as a value in the property step. This is failing because I can't use the select step inside the property step.

This is my current failing query:

```
await g
        ?.inject([
            { twitterPostId: 'tay', like: true, retweet: false },
            { twitterPostId: 'fay', like: true, retweet: false },
        ])
        .unfold()
        .as('a')
        .select('twitterPostId')
        .as('t')
        .V()
        .hasId(__.select('t'))
        .fold()
        .coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addV().property(t.id, __.select('t'))
        .next();
```

Any thoughts on how else I could accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `property()` can take a traversal as a property value.  I think your issue here is different.

The `fold()` step in Gremlin is a reducing barrier step.  Any use of `as()` labels in a traversal are lost once you cross a reducing barrier.  Instead of using `as('t')`, try using `aggregate('t')`.  Then inside of the `property()` step, do a `select('t').unfold()`...  such as:

```
await g
        ?.inject([
            { twitterPostId: 'tay', like: true, retweet: false },
            { twitterPostId: 'fay', like: true, retweet: false },
        ])
        .unfold()
        .as('a')
        .select('twitterPostId')
        .aggregate('t')
        .V()
        .hasId(__.select('t'))
        .fold()
        .coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addV().property(t.id, __.select('t').unfold())
        .next();
```

Comment: That worked thank you! But I got another issue now, I switch the ```V()..hasId(__.select('t'))``` step to ```V(__.select('t'))```, but I'm getting this error now: "Expected an id that is convertible to String but received class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.DefaultGraphTraversal\".

Also tried ```V(__.select('t').unfold())``` and it returned the same error, and if it wasn't clear this failed as well ```V()..hasId(__.select('t'))```

Comment: So as of today, you cannot use `select()` inside of a `V()`.  You'd most likely need to run two queries at this point - one to fetch the vertex IDs that you need and another to submit them as a list of vertex IDs in the following query.

Comment: I opened a Jira for this, in case you want to +1 it.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2777